# Auth problem with creating Cloud Build Triggers

Tags: authentication, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I seem to have gotten my Google/Github authentication into some kind of bad state. I am attempting (repeatedly) to create a Github build trigger by the following steps:

1. From https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers click
   "Create trigger"
2. Select Github and check the consent box.
3. Sign in to my Github account. This succeeds and I see the list of my repositories and my organization's repositories.
4. No matter what repository I select, I see this error:

[There's a problem at our end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur2HL.png)

I've tried include signing out and in of my Github and Google accounts (including clearing all cookies) but nothing helps. I also asked another administrator to create the trigger and he sees the same error, which implies the issue must relate somehow between Google and Github and isn't specific to my personal account?

If anyone has seen this before or has any suggestions it would be a big help. Thanks!